# Display displot in separate subplots - Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm aiming to insert a Seaborn display into separate subplots. Using below, I want to pass `Label1` to `ax1` and `Label2` to `df2`. However, I'm getting a warning: `UserWarning: displot is a figure-level function and does not accept the ax= paramter. You may wish to try histplot. warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)`

Is there a way around this? I've had issues with `histplot` previously in regards to the `hue` parameter. I'm reluctant to use that if necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (12,6))

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,2,3,3,1,3],
    'Label1' : ['A','B','C','B','B','C','C','B','B','A','C','A','B','A','C','A'],  
    'Label2' : ['D','E','D','F','E','D','F','E','F','D','E','F','E','D','D','F'],   
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right','Down','Right','Up','Up','Right','Down','Left'],        
   })

ax1 = sns.displot(data = df, 
               x = 'Label1', 
               hue = 'Num',
               row = 'Item', 
               row_order = ['Up','Down','Left','Right'],
               shrink = 0.9, 
               discrete = True,
               aspect = 4, 
               height = 2,
               ax = ax1
               )

ax2 = sns.displot(data = df, 
               x = 'Label2', 
               hue = 'Num',
               row = 'Item', 
               row_order = ['Up','Down','Left','Right'],
               shrink = 0.9, 
               discrete = True,
               aspect = 4, 
               height = 2,
               ax = ax2
               )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid `histplot()`, I think the closest you can get with `displot()` is to `melt()` the data and use `col` to put `Label1` and `Label2` into two columns:

```py
sns.displot(
    data = df.melt(['Num', 'Item'], var_name='Group', value_name='Label'),
    y = 'Label',
    hue = 'Num',
    row = 'Item',
    col = 'Group',
    row_order = ['Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right'],
    shrink = 0.9,
    discrete = True,
    aspect = 4,
    height = 2,
)
```

[image: displot with 2 cols]